# Which Force.com license for personal use (one person for Admin+developer+user)purpose?

Tags: licenses

I'm building a small application on force.com for my personal user. Which force.com license suits for my case. Basically there's only one user for this new org with me as the user, admin and developer.

I read SFDC's force.com license comparison chart. Seems if I need to write any apex, then I have to buy a Force.com Admin license. Is this true for my case? I have to buy a force.com admin license which is more expensive then regular Force.co license?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, what's the price for Force.com Admin? is it the same price as regular Force.com end user license?

Comment: You could try starting with a [Developer account](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup).

Answer (score 3):

If you're building an app, but not using real production data in it a [free developer edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) is the best option.

If you're building the app to be distributed to other users (i.e. the appexchange, but you aren't required to use that) you can register as a salesforce ISV partner and [get a two-user enterprise edition org for production use](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Business_Org). You can create developer edition orgs with enhanced limits from the environment hub feature if you do this. In this case there's [a document designed to guide you through this process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm).

If you are building just for your own use, then you're right that you'd need a force.com admin license. They are, last time I checked, the same price as force.com platform licenses. You *must* have one admin user to manage the org, so generally one per 50 of your force.com licenses can be promoted to this type at no extra charge. The admin user is actually implemented as a user with full rights to CRM features, and is called a "Salesforce" instead of "Salesforce Platform" license type in your org, but is contractually limited to not use them.

This may vary depending on who you talk to at salesforce, but seems to generally be true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a quick double check, for my own personal use (only myself as user/developer/admin),  I need one  force.com platform license, and one force.com admin license, right?

Comment: You'd just need the admin license if you're going to be the only user. It can do everything the platform license can, plus more.

Comment: How do you actually get a Platform Admin license? Support and our AE say it doesn't exist, even though the [comparison chart](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/salesforce-platform-pricing-editions.pdf) for Platform Starter/Plus mentions it in the footnote.